# How can I utilize `this.userId` from a Meteor Method call?

Tags: meteor

Currently I have two apps, 'Alpha' and 'Bravo', split-up to reduce code size. However now I need 'Bravo' app to call a Meteor method written in the 'Alpha' app (from the client) and it needs to utilize the `this.userId` for security. However, currently `this.userId` is null if called from 'Bravo' app.

The 'Bravo' app creates users by duplicating `createUser` code and sharing the same database. The user can log into each app with no issues. It also connects to Alpha using:
`AlphaDDP = DDP.connect(alpha_server_url)`

However when in Bravo app if I call `AlphaDDP.call('updateDoc', docId, newData)`
the `this.userId` value prints out null in the Alpha logs. I assumed that when I connect with `DDP.connect` it would authenticate the connection. However this doesn't seem to be the case.

After googling I came across `Meteor.call("login")` but it appears this won't work if the user isn't using email/password to log in.

I tried experimenting with the new `AccountsClient` but couldn't make any headway.

Also another caveat is that I need it to work with the accounts SMS login and the accounts need to be created on the 'Bravo' app.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want two apps that share some code and the same db, you should look at **package based architecture**.  This will allow you to split your code into packages, and selectivly import the relevent code into each app.

[meteorpatterns.com has a good guide on this approach.](http://meteorpatterns.com/Sewdn/project-builds)

Comment: Thanks but i'm using Webpack to organize code and can share most of the common code with private NPM modules. I mentioned duplicating the `createUser` func but it's a bit different between apps but close enough to consider them the same for troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: [Is this you?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-webpack-es6-modules-hot-code-patching-fixes-load-order-more/9110)  I've been meaning to try this out.

Comment: Anyway it sounds like you need two different ways to call `updateDoc` on Alpha.  You can probably refactor the logic in it into a function (not Meteor.Method) on the server, that is called by two Meteor.Methods.  Check this.userId in one Meteor.Method when called by Alpha's clients, and call the second Meteor.Method (wrapper) from Beta, with different authentication (signed request, etc).  Also the [`setUserId`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_setUserId) function may come in handy.

Comment: Yep that's me :) The `updateDoc` is the same so I think i'm going to roll my own secondary auth and use a JWT token to auth. then method. I also opened up an issue on Meteor to see what MDG thinks.